# How to apply Retry Untill method on array of elements in Karate

Tags: karate

Want to retry untill response.status !="Running" &&  response.logDetails[*].status !="Running"

Could you please suggest how this can achevied, i am new to karate and not abel to find a way

```
Sample JSON:

{
    "id": 29,
    "loadingId": 18,
    "jobs": [
        "CURRENCY_US"
    ],
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "progress": 100,
    "logDetails": [
        {
            "itemId": 1,
            "dataloaderId": 1,
            "taskName": "task1",
            "status": "COMPLETED",
           
        },
        {
           "itemId": 2,
            "dataloaderId": 2,
            "taskName": "task2",
            "status": "RUNNING",
        },
        {
             "itemId": 3,
            "dataloaderId": 3,
            "taskName": "task3",
            "status": "COMPLETED",
        },
        {
           "itemId": 4,
            "dataloaderId": 4,
            "taskName": "task4",
            "status": "RUNNING",
        }
    ],
    "websocket": true
}
```